# Windows XP clock resets to January 1 2005 and can't be changed

Tags: windows-xp

My PC's clock can't be adjusted. Whenever I try to reset the time in the taskbar the time is always set to January 1 2005. This means that I'm unable to browse some websites since the certificates are rendered invalid.

Could this be caused by a virus? Or something else? The PC works fine except for this clock issue.

Comment: There should never be a point where your unable to navigate a website just because the certification is invalid.  This seems to indicate a larger problem if that is the case, most of the time when I see an invalid certificate, it expired a day or a week ago and I ignore the warning.

Comment: @Ramhound: Actually, if your system clock is off by more than a couple hours, Windows Update (even the old XP version) will not work. So this is not an unheard of problem.

Comment: @Ramhound: HTTPS certificates have attributes "not valid before" and "not valid after" - if your system clock is outside the range, browser will complain of invalid certificate; this is correct behavior. Suggesting to flat-out ignore the warning, regardless of the reason, is very bad advice.

Comment: @Piskvor - Its not bad advice if the certificate happens to have just expired, its important to take the error into context.

Comment: @Ramhound: I have misunderstood you, then, as saying "eh, I just ignore it, it's probably a recently-expired cert anyway". Glad that we're in agreement there :)

Answer (score 6):

You should check your BIOS clock settings.

If your BIOS clock is also reset to that time and date, it is likely that your BIOS battery is fully discharged and must be replaced. This battery a largish watch battery on the mainboard and you should be able to get a replacement from Radio Shack or most other electronics stores. Walmart may even carry them in their watch department.